# Trouble with Java Graphics2D

Tags: java, 2d, user-interface

In my game, I'm using different kinds of objects that implement the `Paint` interface including `GradientPaint` for the background. When I try to paint the background, it mostly leaves a grey border on the right and bottom sides of the screen; I don't want that border there. How can I get rid of it?

I notice that when I set my `JFrame` to be resizable instead of not, the background paints okay as want, but then people will be able to resize the window and distort the visuals needed to play the game.

What I am using to draw graphics is the outdated AWT, using both `Graphics` and `Graphics2D`. All the backgrounds I'm painting consist of either one, two, or four `Rectangle2D.Float` objects, with the appropriate sizes. For a full background, it would be `0`, `0`, `gamePanel.getPreferredSize().width` and `gamePanel.getPreferredSize().height`.

Comment: getPrefferedSize() might not be the same as actual size

Comment: I got the problem fixed using getSize() instead, but what are some good alternatives you know?

Comment: I'm not sure what alternatives you're looking for. Is it solved or not?

Comment: Yes. You can lock the question now. I'm only asking if there would be any other ways to paint something on an entire JPanel than just having to use the getSize() method. Thanks for your help, by the way.